# ASP.NET Core : intercept DbContext connection timeout exception inside controller

Tags: c#, exception, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application where I inject a `DbContext` into a controller. I want to know if there is a way to intercept the connection timeout exception while constructing the `DbContext` returning a specific error response code.

I noticed that the exception is thrown inside the method `AddDbContext` in the Startup class:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                ServerVersion.AutoDetect(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")), o => 
                {
                    o.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery);
                });
        });
```

**EDIT**: Could the exception be thrown from the AutoDetect option which opens a connection to the DB to retrieve its version? I'm using the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql NuGet package, version 5.0.0

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want that? A DbContext isn't a connection, it's a Unit-of-Work. It works disconnected and only opens a short-lived connection when loading data, or when persisting all cached changes when `SaveChanges` is called. If you want to catch a timeout exception use a normal exception handling block around the `ToList` or `SaveChanges` cals

Comment: Alternatively, you could implement a command interceptor and/or execution strategy. This specific link is for SQL Server, but the base infrastructure works for all database types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-resilient-entity-framework-core-sql-connections

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think the problem here is the AutoDetect option used to detect the running version of MySql instance. Behind the scene, it opens a connection to the DB to retrieve its version. So, maybe the question is: How to intercept this timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `ServerVersion.AutoDetect()` method to automatically get your database server version, then you usually want to query it only once on application startup and then reuse it in your `UseMySql()` calls:

```cs
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
var serverVersion = ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString);

services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options
    .UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion, o => o
        .UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery)));
```

In addition, if you want some retry logic for `ServerVersion.AutoDetect()`, take a look at [Missing retry policy for ServerVersion.AutoDetect() #1368](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1368).

You can also explicitly set your server version by using the `MySqlServerVersion` or `MariaDbServerVersion` classes.

> Could the exception be thrown from the AutoDetect option which opens a connection to the DB to retrieve its version? I'm using the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql NuGet package, version 5.0.0

Yes, that is where the exception gets thrown in your case. Otherwise, the exception would be thrown when the `DbContext` first needs the database connection (usually when you execute your first query), which is sometime later *after* calling `AddDbContext()`.